UML aggregation of user access to multiple components
Got the following diagram of a building block view level 1 (no technical unit allowed here). Each component shown has an interaction with users. The UML port (baz) at the top should visualize the user access. Do I really need to draw a dependency from the UML port "baz" to each component, or can I aggregate user access to all components in some way?

I've tried drawing dependency lines from each component to the top UML port - but this looks messy.

You can always use nesting/grouping/classifier nodes...  E.g. see here: https://www.uml-diagrams.org/component-diagrams.html

Yes, you need to draw dependency lines to each component. If that looks messy, maybe your design is messy. Or maybe, it's just necessary. Remember, if your design is complicated, the diagram will - and should - reflect it. By visualizing the complicated structure, it is at least easier to reason about it.
Now the question is, whether the interface is really the same for all components? If not, you need to have separate ports anyway. And then it is important to know which component talks to which port.

I have three interfaces that are responsible for interacting with different user roles. Should each port also be visible in my technical system context diagram, where the above system is a blackbox? Currently I have one port on the system context (blackbox) that marks the user interaction with my system, but in the whitebox there are three different interfaces.

Or in other words: Should each UML port in the system context (black box) display a counterpart in the component views (level 1 + 2) below?

This answer is essentially wrong: 1) readability is crucial; 2) nesting/grouping/classifier nodes exist, and exist for a reason.

@JulioDiEgidio "wrong" is a strong word here. I didn't say that readability is not crucial. However, showing wrong information to make it more readable is not helpful. Your model must show correct information. You can make it more abstract, to make it more readable, but there is a limit to this. It must be just concrete enough for its purpose. Now, what is the purpose of a model of a user port that is not connected to the specific components? How exactly would "nesting/grouping/classifier nodes" help here?

If you want the blackbox and whitebox views to be connected, the ports must be the same. After all, ports are used on encapsulated classifiers to make it possible to treat them as black boxes. All you need to know about them are the ports. In the white box  view, you can see how the externally visible ports are connected to internal parts.
Having said that, it is of course possible to have different levels of abstraction for the two views. Do you need two different formally unconnected models on different abstraction levels?
